# MySQL count rows with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id  status     user_id
 1  decline     8
 2  approved    7
 3  approved    7   
 4  decline     8
 5  decline     7
```

I want result like this:

```
accept_status decline_status user_id
   2                 1         7
   0                 2         8
```

Comment: generally, you should post your attempt, and describe what is not working.  this is not a 'do it for me' site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for free services

Comment: Show su what have you tried to do

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  id int,
  status varchar(20),
  user_id int
  );
  
INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES(1,'decline',8);
 INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES(2,'approved',7);
 INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES(3,'approved',7);
 INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES(4,'decline',8);
 INSERT INTO TEST
VALUES(5,'decline',7);
```

---

**Query #1**
Used two `subqueries` during `SELECT` operation

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT count(status) FROM TEST b WHERE status='approved' AND b.user_id = a.user_id) as accept_status, 
 (SELECT count(status) FROM TEST c WHERE status='decline' AND c.user_id = a.user_id) as decline_status, 
 a.user_id
FROM TEST a
GROUP BY user_id;
```

**OR**

**Query #2**

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when status = 'approved' then 1 else 0 end) AS accept_status,
    sum(case when status = 'decline' then 1 else 0 end) AS decline_status,
    user_id
FROM TEST
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Output**

| accept_status | decline_status | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 0 | 2 | 8 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEwrfDtqRVHTG879swpTih/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using SubQuery or Sub Select you can try this query:

```
select distinct user_id,
(select count(*) from testtable 
     where status='approved' and user_id=a.user_id) as accept_status,
(select count(*) from testtable 
     where status='decline' and user_id=a.user_id) as denied_status
from testtable a;
```